# Unable to use FQL with my Facebook application

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am aware of the fact that FQL has been depricated in recent versions of API.

But I wish to be able to use FQL as long as I can for my app. The problem is I am not able to select old api version for this app [ what is compatible with FQL].

Older API options appears when I choose application as `Graph API Explorer`. 
[image]

But as after I select my own Facebook app , my api version options are limited to `2.3` . 
[image]

I tried selecting unrevisioned which is supposed to select the oldest API version available but I still get the error.

```
  {
  "error": {
    "message": "(#12) fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 12
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you shouldn't use FQL, just move to Graph API, with a slight graph theory learning curve, you should eventually get the hang of it.

BUT From the [Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/versions#calling_older_versions)

> Can my app make calls to versions older than the current version?
>
> An app can make calls to the version of the API that was the latest
>   available when the app was created, as well as any newer,
>   un-deprecated versions launched after the app is created.
>
> Here's an example:
>
> If your app was created before the launch of v2.0, while v1.0 was
>   available, then it will be able to make calls to v1.0 until the
>   expiration date of that version. If your app was created after v2.0
>   was released, it will be able to make calls to v2.0 until the
>   expiration date of that version, and any subsequent versions (v2.1
>   etc) until their expiration dates. If an app is created and isn't used
>   to make any calls or requests before a new version is released, it
>   will not have the ability to use older versions. Here's an example to
>   explain this:
>
> If your app was created while v2.0 was the latest version available,
>   but not used until after v2.1 had launched, it will only be to use
>   v2.1, and not v2.0. If your app was created while v2.0 was the latest
>   version available, and then used before v2.1 had launched, it will
>   still be able to use v2.0 even after the launch of v2.1.

so when was your app created and used ? 
FQL should be accessible if your app was created and used during Facebook V2.0 before 2.1 came along and V2.0 is available till August 7, 2016